# edit queries are writing over all records

Tags: php, sql

Im having some issues will my queries in my model. I have this edit function and inside that is a foreach that controls what gets updated and inserted where. the problem Im having is the last set of else statements that write to the communication table.

The records being written are tied to an overall campaign id. that id is stored to each record. So each record may have its own communication_id but they all would have the same campaign_id.

So currently setting the WHERE to campaign_id edits all records. I need to use the communication_id in this instance but how do I get it before the communication queries? Say a record has communication_id 50 I want to get that id and then use that in the WHERE. Im not sure how to do that though.

```
public function editCampaign($campaign_id, $data) {

        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "campaigns SET campaign_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_name']) . "', campaign_giving_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_goal']
        . "', code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['code']) . "', campaign_active = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_active']) . "', campaign_giving_count_goal = '" . (float)$data['campaign_giving_count_goal'] . "', campaign_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($data['campaign_owner']). "'
        , date_beginning = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "' WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

        $parent_id = 0;

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_components WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
        //$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "communication WHERE campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");
        foreach($data['component_module'] as $component_data) {

            if ($component_data['component_type'] =='EVENT'){

            if(isset($component_data['component_parent_id'])){
                $parent_id = $component_data['component_parent_id'];

                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', date_starting = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_start_date']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "', date_added = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', language_id = '1' WHERE product_id ='" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
            }else{

                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', date_starting = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_beginning']). "', date_ending = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_ending']). "', date_added = NOW()");
                $parent_id = $this->db->getLastId();

                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', language_id = '1', product_id ='" . (int)$parent_id . "'");
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category SET category_id = '82', product_id ='" . (int)$parent_id . "' ");

            }

        }else{
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "communication SET subject = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', channel = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "'
            , status_date = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_start_date']). "', status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "', created_by = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_owner']) . "', date_added = NOW(), campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "'");

        }
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_components SET component_name = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_name']) . "', component_type = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_type']) . "', component_status = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_status']) . "'
            , component_owner = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_owner']). "', component_start_date = '" . $this->db->escape($component_data['component_start_date']). "', campaign_id = '" . (int)$campaign_id . "', parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "'");

    }

        $this->cache->delete('parent_id');

        return $campaign_id;
    }
```

Comment: Please learn to use prepared statements instead of concatenating variables.

Answer (score 0):

Join with the `communication` table:

```
UPDATE campaigns AS ca
JOIN communication AS co ON ca.communication_id = co.communication_id
SET ca.col1 = val1, ca.col2 = val2, ...
WHERE co.campaign_id = $campaign_id
```

(I've left out all the PHP variables so you can see the general structure of the query.)